# AngularJS Missing required controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to create **two directives** that have the following structure:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ui-foo="test">
        <div ui-bar="test2"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

First directive is `uiFoo`, the second one is `uiBar`.

To define these directives I have setup the following module definition:

```
angular.module('ui', []).directive('uiFoo', 
    function() {
      return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function($scope, element, attrs) {
            $scope.message = function() {
                alert(1);
            };
        }
      };
    }
  ).directive('uiBar',
    function() {
      return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: '^uiFoo',
        scope: true,
        link: function($scope, element, attrs, uiBarController) {
          uiBarController.message();
        }
      };
    }
  );

angular.module('myApp', ['ui']);
```

The problem that I am experiencing is known as `error/$compile/ctreq` (`Controller 'uiFoo', required by directive 'uiBar', can't be found!`) and the documentation for it can be found here (https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$compile/ctreq?p0=uiFoo&p1=uiBar). I know, a little lackluster.

It doesn't seem to solve my issue.

I've created a JSFiddle for this which you can find here http://jsfiddle.net/A8Vgk/1187/

Thanks!

Comment: The `$` is on the scope, not on the element. Removing it doesn't fix anything, it's just a naming convention. The `link` function just injects the parameters in that specific order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like the error says, you're missing the controller on the `uiFoo` directive.

When you use the `require: ^uiFoo`, it tells Angular that you want to have access to the controller in the directive called `uiFoo`.

You didn't define a controller in that directive, so you get the error.

Just define the controller:

```
angular.module('ui', []).directive('uiFoo', 
    function() {
      return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function($scope, element, attrs) {
            $scope.message = function() {
                alert(1);
            };
        },
          controller: function($scope) {
              this.message = function () {
                  alert("works!");
              }
          }
      };
    }
  )
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A8Vgk/1188/).

Comment: Hm, I thought that by filling in the `scope`, it would act as the controller. Makes sense now. The documentation could use a little polish though. :) Thanks for the help!

Comment: @AdrianMar My pleasure. I agree about the documentation.